# Debian 8 (Jessie) fails to load on reboot with error 'Failed to start Login Service'

Tags: linux, debian

After installing firefox 47.0.1 and uninstalling iceweasel browser, the system asked me to reboot. 
After launching the reboot, Debian has been unable to load completely giving the following message

```
Loading, please wait...

fsck from util-linux 2.25.2

/dev/sda1: clean, 408068/4759552 files, 2946979/19012096 blocks

[FAILED] Failed to start Login Service

..........
....... and so on
```

I think I destroyed something when I tried to move the firefox folder to the `/usr/bin/` directory using the command
`sudo mv firefox /usr/bin`

after which I ran the command `firefox` and had a message that firefox is a folder. Since then my system started behaving funny.
I launched reboot and fell in the arms of 'Failed to start Login Service'. Before I could reboot `sudo` was no longer recognized.

When I run `systemctl status systemd-logind.service`, this what I get

```
systemd-logind.service - Login Serivice
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service; static)
Active: inactive (dead)
Docs: ........... and so on
```

I was working and saw the need to install a modern browser. I wish to know the proper way to recover the system without damaging my work.
I run Debian Jessie on 32 bits intel processor desktop.

Comment: You'll be pleased to know the kvm warning is irrelevant. Please tell us more about "_I tried to move the firefox folder to the `/usr/bin/` directory_". (Don't forget to [edit] your question rather than replying here in the comments.)

Comment: Thanks for citing that out. Please if there be a possibility to bypass 'Failed to start Login Service' or create a different user please let me know.

Comment: The `mv firefox /usr/bin` command shouldn't really have broken anything except `firefox` (even if the item you moved was a folder). I think at this stage you're probably into the realms of booting from a [Rescue CD](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) and seeing whether the permissions on the system directories and files have been damaged by some other command you might have run. I'm particularly concerned about `sudo` no longer being recognised - that suggests your `/usr/bin` directory or its contents may have had its permissions (or location) changed.

Comment: I think you are right. I was confused to see myself in `/usr/bin/sudo:# ` instead of `root@server...:#` something like that, telling me directory not found. I wish to if using a USB in the place of a CD can permit me recover the entire system with my work. Sincerely, I need guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me recently, the machine was shut down in the middle of an apt upgrade. I rebooted into recovery mode and ran `apt upgrade` again and made it through, rebooted and all was running great again.